# Getting cookies from a webview of a specific domain?

Tags: android, cookies, webview

I looked around for a solution for this, but here goes:

I have an application and I want to track exactly when someone installed it from my domain (let's say the app is app.apk).

So I have a landing page, which is basically a link to download the apk, once someone enters the page, I set a cookie on their device, and what I want to know now, is if it's possible and how can I read that cookie in an app. (let's say the path of my cookie is `domain example.com/android/`)

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

code snippet to load a webpage in webView and read cookies for this page on server .

```
            myWebView = new WebView(this);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }

    });
    setContentView(myWebView);

    CookieManager.getInstance().removeSessionCookie();
    myWebView.loadUrl(URL);
```

//where you want to read cookies

```
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
                final String cookie = cookieManager.getCookie(URL);
                Log.i(TAG, "cookie " + cookie);
```